# Installing Angular 5 on express

Tags: angular, typescript, express

How to install angular 5 on existing express project ?

Here are my files :

[image: Express project on webstorm]

Package.json :

[image: Package]

**I want to install angular 5 on this and build front-end. How should I install angular 5 on this express project?  What are the steps of doing it ?**

Comment: all the negative voting aside - lets state the obvious - they are two different projects , you could have a node dir inside the front end project.     You have been kicked enough on voting

Comment: Angular gives the static files which can be served using express. You can read this documentation https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install angular 5 onto you express.js server. Visualize them as their own projects both having their own localhost/port and routes. You can literally create a angular 5 app without the need of your express.js server. Look into using https://cli.angular.io/. When you start up your express.js server it defaults to localhost:3000. When you start up an angular 5 app it defaults to localhost:4200.

Comment: How to connect them both ? Express and angular

Comment: you dont need to connect them both. You have them talk to each other via http requests.